# Need help toggling google chrome extension webRequest listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

Hey guys I'm really new to making google chrome extensions. The first extension I decided to do was a simple website blocker. I have found some code from somebody's answer on here that can toggle the webRequest listener based on tab.id as seen below:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
if (listeners[tab.id]) { //If the ID already exists
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(listeners[tab.id]);
    delete listeners[tab.id];
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'OFF',
        tabId: tab.id
    });
} else {
    listeners[tab.id] = function(details) {
        return {cancel: true};
    };
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(listeners[tab.id], {
        urls: user,
        types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
        tabId: tab.id
    }, ['blocking']);
    // Show indicator to show that the extension is active.
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'ON',
        tabId: tab.id
    });
}
});
```

This works great for each tab, however I would like to toggle the listener for ALL tabs. 
How I would like it to work:

- Click Extension Icon
- Blocks all URLs that are in my 'user' array no matter if I switch tabs or not
- Can click icon again to disable no matter if tab is different from the tab I originally enabled the extension.

I have tried many times to recreate this method, however I cannot remove the listen once it is enabled. Because my implementation always calls an anonymous function, and from what I've read you cannot remove a listener where the call back function was anonymous.

Here is some basic implementation I tried on my own:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
if(toggle===true)
    toggle = false;
else if(toggle===false)
    toggle = true;

if(toggle===true){
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function deny(request) {
        return {cancel: true}; 
    }, { urls: user, types: [] }, ["blocking"]);

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'ON'
    });
}
else{
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener();
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'OFF'
    });
}

});
```

Basically I would like some help converting the first code segment into one that works for all tabs. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've successfully identified the problem: you cannot remove a listener if the callback function is anonymous. Great! This is because you need to pass the exact same object to `addListener` and `removeListener`.

All you have to do, then, is instead of using an anonymous function, keep that function somewhere you can access it. For example, you could define the function `deny` outside of the `onClicked` listener, then pass `deny` to both `onBeforeRequest.addListener` and `onBeforeRequest.removeListener`.

(A note about your code: you can flip the value of toggle with `toggle = !toggle`, and test if toggle is true by using `if (toggle)` rather than `if (toggle === true)`. These are just common idioms.)